# Pgfplots: Limiting grid lines or extending arrowhead of x-y axis in simple Cartesian plane

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am attempting to create a simple Cartesian plane using pgfplots, where the positive ends of the x and y-axis extend slightly past the square grid. So far, what I have is as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=middle,
            axis line style=->,
            xmin=-10,xmax=10,
            ymin=-10,ymax=10,
            grid=both,
            grid style={draw=gray!25},
            xtick={-10, -8, ..., 10}, xtick style={yshift=-0.5ex},
            ytick={-10, -8, ..., 10}, ytick style={xshift=-0.5ex},
            yticklabel style={xshift=-0.5ex},
            minor tick num=1,
            minor tick length=0.5ex,
            minor x tick style={yshift=0.25ex}, minor y tick style={xshift=0.25ex},
        ]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

For reference, here is the template I'm attempting to replicate.

[image]

By extending the xmax/ymax values, the grid lines by default extend to these values. Would anyone have any suggestions on either limiting the grid length or extending the positive axis ends?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome! You can use `shorten` and use a negative distance.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=middle,
            axis line style={-stealth,shorten >=-3mm},
            xmin=-10,xmax=10,
            ymin=-10,ymax=10,
            grid=both,
            grid style={draw=gray!25},
            xtick={-10, -8, ..., 10}, xtick style={yshift=-0.5ex},
            ytick={-10, -8, ..., 10}, ytick style={xshift=-0.5ex},
            yticklabel style={xshift=-0.5ex},
            minor tick num=1,
            minor tick length=0.5ex,
            minor x tick style={yshift=0.25ex}, minor y tick style={xshift=0.25ex},
        ]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with x and y labels.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=middle,
            axis line style={-stealth,shorten >=-3mm},
            xmin=-10,xmax=10,
            ymin=-10,ymax=10,
            xlabel=$x$,
            every axis x label/.style={at={(xticklabel cs:1,0)},
            yshift=1.8em,
            anchor=south west},
            ylabel=$y$,
            every axis y label/.style={at={(yticklabel cs:1,0)},
            xshift=2.7em,yshift=0.2em,
            anchor=south east},
            grid=both,
            grid style={draw=gray!25},
            xtick={-10, -8, ..., 10}, xtick style={yshift=-0.5ex},
            ytick={-10, -8, ..., 10}, ytick style={xshift=-0.5ex},
            yticklabel style={xshift=-0.5ex},
            minor tick num=1,
            minor tick length=0.5ex,
            minor x tick style={yshift=0.25ex}, minor y tick style={xshift=0.25ex},
        ]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, I never knew that was an option. This is perfect, thank you. Out of curiosity, I noticed you replaced `axis line style=->` to get the desired result. How does the code still retain the arrowhead preferences?

Comment: @BradHall You can change back to `->`, I just thought `stealth` looks better.